# How to get the latest JSON element via PHP?

Tags: php, json

Each time a new status and time is added to the sub-row. Below is an example as JSON datas. I want to get the latest status and time element via PHP.

```
[
    {
        "status": "NEW",
        "time":"2018-07-25T06:26:05Z" 
    },

    {
        "status": "EXPIRED",
        "time":"2018-07-25T06:41:13Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Like search "last element of array php" on google ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your questions, need more information like how the json generated and from where you want to get json data in your php etc.

Comment: With the array.

Comment: you can use $j_data =  json_decode($json) and access the latest one using echo $j_data[sizeof($j_data)]

Comment: Sort the array using the `time` column, then get the last element.

Comment: @ShahriatHossain That will try to access outside the array, it should be `count($j_data)-1`

Comment: @Zyigh latest != last

Comment: @Barmar it depends on if his record stay in the last one

Comment: @HighCoder If you are fetching this from database, add auto incremented ID with data so you can easily sort data using latest id.

Comment: @ShahriatHossain It doesn't depend on anything. Array indexes go from `0` to `count-1`.

Comment: @SambhajiKatrajkar Sorting by ID will only return the latest record if the time column contains the time that the row was inserted, not some other unrelated time.

Comment: @Barmar May be he is fetching statuses of something and he wants the latest status of that thing. Status change will happen according to latest id.

Answer (score 0):

IF you Decode json using php,you will gate array for same JSON. PHP have one function of array is end().this function give last element of your array.this will give you latest JSON element.

Comment: end() gives last element not latest element.

Comment: This will only give you the latest element if the array is sorted by time.

Comment: json_decode() won't return array by default. You need to pass `true` in second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're after but it may help point you towards the right direction. This requires PHP7 for the spaceship operator `<=>`.

```
<?php

$json = '[{"status": "NEW", "time":"2018-07-25T06:26:05Z"}, {"status": "EXPIRED", "time":"2018-07-25T06:41:13Z"}]';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    // Error Handling.
}

// Sort into Time Order
usort($decoded, function ($a, $b) {
    return new DateTime($a['time']) <=> new DateTime($b['time']);
});

echo end($decoded)['status']; // EXPIRED
```

If you want a Non-PHP7 version let me know and i'll provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Here i mentioned one example code as per what you need.we have an array of an element disordered by key "time".you can sort an array by user defined function in ascending order and then get last element of your array by using php end() function.that will give you latest record.

It is a sample array that you got after decode json.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => new
            [time] => 2018-07-25T06:26:05Z
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [status] => new
        [time] => 2018-07-25T06:52:05Z
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [status] => EXPIRED
        [time] => 2018-07-25T06:41:13Z
    )
```

)

then by using below code

```
$a =array(
array('status'=>"new","time"=>"2018-07-25T06:26:05Z"),
array('status'=>"new","time"=>"2018-07-25T06:52:05Z"),
array('status'=>"EXPIRED","time"=>"2018-07-25T06:41:13Z")
```

);

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
if(strtotime($a['time']) == strtotime($b['time'])) {
    return 0;
}
return (strtotime($a['time']) < strtotime($b['time'])) ? -1 : 1;
```

}

```
uasort($a, 'cmp');
print_r($a);
```

you will get this output

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => new
            [time] => 2018-07-25T06:26:05Z
        )

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [status] => EXPIRED
        [time] => 2018-07-25T06:41:13Z
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [status] => new
        [time] => 2018-07-25T06:52:05Z
    )
```

)

so you will get latest record at last element of an array.